# Node JS Frontend and Backend

Tags: node.js, meteor, frontend, backend

while meteor js is not running on arm processors in the newest version i'm trying to switch to pure node js.

I don't know what the best solution is for my purpose.

I need a frontend (maybe vuejs or express js) and a backend for saving things into a database.
A great thing of vue js is that i can run a "build" for getting pure html with javascript which can run with apache or nginx.

But a backend has to run with node js.

So it doesn't seems to be the best solution, because i have to run apache and node js on my pi which has not much ram.

The problem is that i need to have a realtime connection to the backend which is not very easy with a javascript frontend and a php backend (so i don't need to run apache and node js).

What can i do to run a realtime app with frontend and backend and only one webserver (software)?

Answer (score 1):

Meteor can easily be made to run under pure node.js by creating a [production bundle](http://docs.meteor.com/commandline.html#meteorbuild). However, with a local MongoDB as well, this solution will still require a lot of resources, which might be too much for a Pi.

It sounds like your use case is maybe better served by something like for example [GUN](http://gun.js.org/).

You could also look at [Horizon](https://horizon.io/). Since the RethinkDB Company closed down it has no official support, but the database has been resurrected by the community and Horizon might well be too.